# How can I use php preg_replace & the same 'match' twice?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following PHP `preg_replace`

```
            $src = preg_replace
            (
            array(
                '/(?si)<p\s+class\s*=\s*"Heading1(.*?)"\s*>(.*?)<\/p>/'
            ),
            array(
                "<h1>$2<tocentry content='$2' level='0' /></h1>"
            ),
                $src
            );
```

The preg_replace searches a HTML document for any `<p>` with the class `Heading1` and should replace it with something like:

```
<h1>Introduction<tocentry content='Introduction' level='0' /></h1>
```

However, what I'm actually getting is:

```
<h1>Introduction<tocentry content='span class=' level='0' /></h1>
```

I'm using the same match reference ('2') - however am receiving a different result for each. How can this be?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

It appears the problem was in the HTML I was `preg_replacing` (`$src`).

The `<p>` had a `<span>` as a child, which was causing the strange result.

I am now using the following, which works fine:

```
$src = preg_replace
(
array(
    '/(?si)<span\s+class\s*=\s*"Heading1-H(.*?)"\s*>(.*?)<\/span>/'
),
array(
    "<h1>$2<tocentry content='$2' level='0' /></h1>"
), 
    $src
);
```

Comment: Try changing \\2 into $2 as you used at the first reference.

Comment: There may be something blindingly obvious I am missing, but why is one `$2` and one `\\2`?

Comment: Hi DaveRandom, TRD - $2 and \\2 return the same result "span class=" - I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: I would recommend changing the first `(.*?)` to something like `([^"]*)`. This may or may not fix your problem, but I think that matching *any* character (including, potentially, the closing `"`) is dangerous...

Comment: @DaveRandom that's not the issue. It's a lazy search and will capture all characters until the first `"` is reached. But using `[^"]*` is more efficient since it won't have to backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

```
$src = <<<EOD
   <sometag>Content here content here content here</sometag>
   <p class="Heading1stuffstuff">Introduction</p>
   <anothertag> More Content. </anothertag>
EOD;

$result = preg_replace (
  array(
    '/<p\s+class\s*=\s*"Heading1([^"]*)"\s*>([^<]*)<\/p>/si'
  ),
  array(
    "<h1>$2<tocentry content='$2' level='0' /></h1>"
  ),
  $src
);

print $result;

/* Outputs:
   <sometag>Content here content here content here</sometag>
   <h1>Introduction<tocentry content='Introduction' level='0' /></h1>
   <anothertag> More Content. </anothertag>
*/
```

**NB** Syntax Highlighting is dodgy because SO doesn't like HEREDOCs, but it does work... honest...

Comment: Thanks DaveRandom - but I appear to be getting a slightly different result - my <p>'s now appear untouched - like <p class="Heading1">Introduction</p>

Comment: Please edit your question with a sample of the HTML you are running this against.

Comment: Thanks DaveRandom - looking at the HTML in detail seems to have solved my problem...see my edit :)